# I need sudo without password prompt, for scripts. Where did I go wrong?

Tags: linux, git, sudo

I am in sudo group all right:

```
$ id
uid=1002(molot) gid=1002(molot) groups=1002(molot),27(sudo),33(www-data)
```

In my sudores I seem to have appropriate setting:

```
sudo    ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

and it is the last uncommented line there.

But when I try to `git pull`, I'm asped to retype my password:

```
$ sudo -u www-data git --git-dir /var/www/.git --work-tree /var/www pull "origin" master
[sudo] password for molot:
```

It is not a problem when I am logged in console, but it is unacceptable in scripts. So how can I allow anyone in sudo group to git pull as www-data without retyping password?

When I put my name directly:

```
molot ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

it works for me. But, obviously, not for marian or other users from sudo group. As far as I understood [manual](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html), both usernames and group names should work in first file.

Comment: Can you not `sudo -u www-data ./your_script.sh`?  What is the purpose of the script?

Comment: @jimbobmcgee it's a git hook, so no, I cannot prepend anything to it. It is called by the user who pushed git changes and I found no real way around it.

Comment: The first field (if my quick understanding of the `sudoers` file format is correct) is the username of the invoking user. Have you tried replacing it with the wildcard `*`, or whichever user the git hook runs as?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling as stated [here](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html) it should be possible to write both users and groups in first field. `*` does not work. Putting my name directly works for me... but not for other users in sudo group, obviously.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling thank you, your comment made me to look for special chars and allowed me to find an answer :D Edit: deleted self answer and accepted 3rd party answer from the same moment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Seems you've got the relevant line in your sudoers missing a character:

> sudo    ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

matches an user named 'sudo'. For 'all users in the sudo group' it should be:

> %sudo    ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

(note the % sign at the beginning).

Comment: Ah so that's what the `%` in `%wheel` meant.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo visudo`

Then, assuming `molot` is your username, go to the end of file and:

`molot ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

This should work, but if it doesn't, keep us posted.

Comment: This works. For me. But, obviously, not for marian or any other user in sudo group.

Comment: Then create user aliases (`User_Alias`), and give permission to run specific commands as root (`Runas_Alias`).


I don't know how your group is set-up, you can check out the Sudoers wiki


https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers


It is really concise. Check the "User Specifications" section, this should help.